# Drupal - Modify tabs added to user page by Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I've added a number of new tabs to the user page, using Views (as a page with menu tab settings etc.). What I now want to do is remove them if the viewed user is the current, logged in user.

Prior to adding some user filtering, my first problem is that I just can't seem to modify these tabs at all. I know the general procedure is to use HOOK_MENU_ALTER and (for example):

```
$items['user/%user/view']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
```

This works fine for the original tabs, but not for tabs added with Views, e.g. for an 'Articles' tab:

```
$items['user/%user/articles']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
```

Are tabs added by Views handled differently to 'normal' tabs?

Cheers,
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you won't be able to hide them dynamically by making them MENU_CALLBACK. What you should do is change the access callback to a function where you would check for the current user.

As for why you can't find the tabs, check if:

- There isn't a menu entry with
  %views_arg instead of %user
- That your module's weight (in the system table) is bigger than views' weight. Since views uses the same hook it's possible that your module gets called before views.

Comment: The tab does indeed use an argument from views, but replacing %user with %views_arg does not seem to work.

Comment: Yup, correct! I was sure the module weight was high, but it wasn't... working now...

Answer (score 1):

I think views is adding all it's stuff in hook_menu_alter(). To change it, you need to give your module a higher weight in the {system} table than views has.

Comment: :( Whoops, double checked the database and the weight was not what I thought it was... changed now.