# Drupal - hook_menu_alter - add access callback to check viewed user profile is not current user

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Can't get my head around this...

I've added a 'contacts' tab on user profiles. What I want to do is hide this if the user profile does NOT belong to the logged in user.

I've got this in an implementation of hook_menu_alter:

```
$items['user/%views_arg/contacts'] = array(
           'access callback'=>'current_user_hide_tabs', 
           'access arguments'=>array(1), 
        );
```

I just can't seem to get the corresponding function to work:

```
function current_user_hide_tabs($user) {
  return $user->uid != $account->uid //???
}
```

Cheers!

(I've checked that the tab is actually being accessed after asking an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143663/drupal-modify-tabs-added-to-user-page-by-views).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks guys for getting me closer to a solution. I found out that it worked if I reference the `$items` variables individually and don't use an array...???

So not:

```
$items['user/%views_arg/contacts'] = array(
   'access callback'=>'current_user_hide_tabs', 
   'access arguments'=>array(1), 
);
```

...but:

```
$items['user/%views_arg/contacts']['access callback'] = 'current_user_hide_tabs';
$items['user/%views_arg/contacts']['access arguments'] = array(1);
```

...and using Matt's function:

```
function current_user_hide_tabs($uid) {
  global $user;
  return $user->uid != $uid;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function current_user_hide_tabs($account) {
  global $user;
  return $user->uid != $account->uid;
}
```

$user: This is the current user, note the global statement so that it is visible inside your function
$account: This is the user account passed to your function. Needs to be renamed because $user is already reserved for the currently logged in user.

Comment: I made a mistake in my question: it should be 'user/%views_arg/contacts' not 'user/%user/contacts', sorry. So I guess I need to change $account->uid to something else?

Comment: Looking http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--views.module/function/views_arg_load/6, I think the argument is simply the user id, but you can always check with dpm($account) if you have devel.module installed.

Comment: In my case yeah, the arg is the user id. I still can't get the function to work though. :(

Comment: just replacing "$account->uid" with "$new_arg" should do the trick. If not, you need to start debugging too verify that your function is called and what $user->uid and your argument exactly is. Oh, actually, now I see it. Instead of "!=" you want "==" because you want to return TRUE when someone has access. Not the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$items['user/%/contacts'] = array(
  'access callback'=>'current_user_hide_tabs', 
  'access arguments'=>array(1), 
); 

function current_user_hide_tabs($uid) {
  global $user;

  return $user->uid == $uid;
}
```

Will return FALSE unless the logged in user's ID is the same as user//contacts thus hiding the menu link. You don't want to compare $user to the access argument because the argument will be a user ID, not a user object. $user->uid is the user ID.

Comment: Cheers. Doesn't seem to work at the moment :( I can't think what's wrong here. I'll think I'll do some tests on non-views tabs to see if they work.